# Java Syntax error on token "}",{ expected after this token

Tags: java

I am unsure about what is causing a Java syntax error on one of my methods. I have provided a comment on the place that has the error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import Products.Items;

public class  ItemProcess{
    private static ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<Items>();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    final int PORT = 1234;
    Socket client;
    ClientHandler handler;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Items[] item = { new Items(123, "ABCDEE fghikop"),
                new Items(180, "hgiuhygihuvg KHJMLOP"), };
        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++)
            itemList.add(item[i]);  
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        int date = start.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = start.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter finishing time in 24-hr format ");
        System.out.print("(e.g. 17:52) :  ");
        String timeString = input.nextLine();


        String hourString = timeString.substring(0,2);
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourString);


        String minString = timeString.substring(3,5);
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(minString);


        Calendar deadline = Calendar.getInstance();

        deadline.set(year,month,date,hour,minute,0);


        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline: "
                            + getDateTime(deadline) + "\n");


        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        while(now.before(deadline))
        {
            System.out.println(getDateTime(now));

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException intEx)
            {

            }


            now = Calendar.getInstance();
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nDeadline reached!!!\n");
    }

    public static String getDateTime(Calendar dateTime)
    {       


        String hour2Digits =
                String.format("%02d",
                        dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        String min2Digits =
                String.format("%02d",
                            dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        return(dateTime.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/"
                + (dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/"
                + dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "  "
                + hour2Digits + ":" + min2Digits);
    } //I am getting the syntax error on here which reads like this "Syntax error on token "}",{ expected after this token



        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

        do
        {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            //Wait for client.
            System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
            handler = new ClientHandler(client);
            handler.start();
        }while (true);
    }


class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket client;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException
    {
        client = socket;

        input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintWriter(
                        client.getOutputStream(),true);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String received;

        do
        {
            received = input.nextLine();
            output.println("ECHO: " + received);
        }while (!received.equals("QUIT"));

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Closing down connection...");
            client.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("* Disconnection problem! *");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: } //I am getting the syntax error on here which reads like this "Syntax error on token "}",{ expected after this token
after one of my methods

Answer (score 2):

You should indent your code properly, it would help you find this type of errors. This code is not inside a method, which is not allowed in Java:

```
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx)
    {
        System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

    do
    {
        client = serverSocket.accept();
        //Wait for client.
        System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
        handler = new ClientHandler(client);
        handler.start();
    }while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a misplaced try catch that is out of any method. I am not sure what you meant there. Right after the `getDateTime` method.

Answer (score 0):

The code after the `getDateTime()` method should be inside a **method block**.currently its not inside any method. place it in appropriate method block.

```
 public void someMethod() {
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
   // rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

That `}` ends your `getDateTime` method, after which you have a stranded bunch of code (below) which needs to be encapsulated in a block somehow.

```
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    }
    catch (IOException ioEx)
    {
        System.out.println("\nUnable to set up port!");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    System.out.println("\nServer running...\n");

    do
    {
        client = serverSocket.accept();
        //Wait for client.
        System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");
        handler = new ClientHandler(client);
        handler.start();
    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this?? I beleive, that code that begins after your comment is out of any function. This is not possible. You should place it in any function.

Also, you can use SimpleDateFormat to convert your date to String in specified format, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```